# Executing a script at each restart of an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I would like to ask you this question: is it possible to execute this script at each restart of an AWS Ec2 instance?

```html
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo install docker
sudo install docker-compose
rm -rf .git
rm -rf /
git clone <URL>
git pull
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Consider I have installed Ubuntu on my istance. I tried to insert its in User Data but it doesn't work... Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: So when you restart the instance you want the machine to execute that script after  it boots? can't you just run that in any daemon  like upstart or systemd?

Comment: Yes I would like to execute the script again but my problem is that Ec2 seems unable to execute its at all...

Answer (score -1):

First, you should fix your bash script.

1. Line 3: missing `apt`: `sudo apt install docker`
2. Line 4: missing `apt`: `sudo apt install docker-compose`
3. Line 6: **Warning**, you are trying to remove `/` here without `sudo`
4. Line 8: To do a `git pull`, you will need to be in the correct path of your previously cloned repository.

To troubleshoot your `user-data` bash scripts, you will need to check logs in:

- `/var/log/cloud-init.log`
- `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Second, If you like to execute this bash **script every** time an EC2 instance is restarted from a stopped state, follow the documentation below. FYI, the standard behavior for user data is to be executed only one time at the first boot cycle.

From AWS Doc :

> By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only
> during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched. However, you
> can configure your user data scripts and cloud-init directives to run
> every time the instance is restarted from a stopped state. For more
> information, see How can I execute user data after the initial launch
> of my EC2 instance? in the AWS Knowledge Center.

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Just add that the bootstrap script seems wrong. OP may need to add 'apt-get' to the mix, as 'sudo install docker' will not work, so probably you are getting errors there.
Once you log into the instance, you can check if your bootstrap script ran properly by checking the logs in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log